# Add days and months on a date time with php

Tags: php, html, dropdown

I want to make a textBox where you can enter a date time and then you choose a option in a dropdown menu. The dropdown menu has a calculation.

For example:

```
if ($exampleMonth === 11 && $exampleDay > 30) {
    $exampleMonth = 12;
    $exampleDay = 1; 
}
```

The dropdown menu is connected with my database:

```
require("require.php");

$oMy = new clsMYSQL();
$oMy->Query("select * IKE_EventTemplate where EventCode in ('H17', 'H18', 'H19', 'H20', 'H21')");
while(!$oMy->eof)
{
    echo  $oMy->row['EventCode'];;
    $hFvg = $oMy->row['EventCode'];

    if ($hFvg === 'H17' || $hFvg === 'H18' || $hFvg === 'H19' || $hFvg === 'H20' || $hFvg === 'H21') {
        //  hFdate = fs.event.eventDate;
        $year = ($hFdate.getFullYear());
        $month = ($hFdate.getMonth());
        $day = ($hFdate.getDate());
```

So I make you a example.

1. You type in "12 October 2018" in the text Box.
2. You choose a option in the dropdown menu called "Example1"
3. You press button "Get solution"
4. Text Box 2 shows the solution = 31. December 2021

[image]

Comment: What is your actual question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: It's amazing how people that write their first question already know about downvotes. It's like if they have lived another life and got reincarnated.... Or maybe they just created a new account in the same life, I don't know. I did not know of the downvotes when I just registered here.

Comment: I'm on stackoverflow a long time but didn't register at all.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I did my own code but I think I can't really make something working because im new in PHP. My question was, if somebody knew how to start and explain how i should do it. Thanks

Comment: SO is a FAQ for when you have specific issues with your existing code. We're glad to help sort bugs/problems out after you've exhausted every other option (by doing a ton of research/attempts etc.). Otherwise, it will simply become a free coding service (which it is not).

Comment: I did a ton of research.. My full code is https://pastebin.com/CW02aPBQ

Answer (score 0):

don't exactly know what you are looking for but maybe this helps:

```
date_add($Date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 month'));//add 1 month of time to the variable $Date
```

you could also use `date_sub()` to subtract days